# stackoverflow syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: vim

Today i woke up with a simple idea.

It would great to have "**stackoverflow synthax highlighting in vim**".

Do you know a simple way to go SO style ?

Comment: do you mean the syntax HL used in SO code block? it depends on the language detection.

Comment: Do you want the colors used by StackOverflow to render code blocks or do you want the syntax highlighting rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses *Markdown* syntax, so this should do it (in Vim versions 7.3+, which ship with it):

```
:setf markdown
```

#### as separate filetype

If you want to do customizations, it's best to define your own custom *stackoverflow* filetype by creating a file `~/.vim/syntax/stackoverflow.vim` with the following contents (and defining corresponding *filetype detection* rules):

```
" Quit when a syntax file was already loaded.
if exists('b:current_syntax') | finish | endif

runtime! syntax/markdown.vim syntax/markdown/*.vim
```

#### filetype setting from browser

Since Stack Overflow is browser-based, you probably use a browser plugin to do the editing in Vim. I've described such a setup that can automatically set the filetype based on the currently edited URL for Firefox in my blog post [Pentadactyl set filetype in external Vim editor based on URL](http://ingo-karkat.de/blog/2012/05/22/Pentadactyl%20set%20filetype%20in%20external%20Vim%20editor%20based%20on%20URL.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fuzzy; if you mean to mark certain blocks as having a certain syntax (which on Stack Overflow can be done with `language: lang-js` HTML comments), my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) enables you to define a different filetype syntax on regions of a buffer, either manually or automatically based on markers.